# Subnet problem in VPC creation via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc

I am a noob in networking. I am creating a VPC via Cloudformation. In that, I have to create 4 subnets. When I run the included template, I see this error:
**Template error: Fn::Select cannot select nonexistent value at index 3**

But, when I create it with 3 subnets, it is fine.

My Template sample:

```
Parameters:

  VpcBlock:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/16
    Description: The CIDR range for the VPC. This should be a valid private (RFC 1918) CIDR range.

  Subnet01Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.0.0/14
    Description: CidrBlock for subnet 01 within the VPC

  Subnet02Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.64.0/14
    Description: CidrBlock for subnet 02 within the VPC

  Subnet03Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.128.0/14
    Description: CidrBlock for subnet 03 within the VPC

  Subnet04Block:
    Type: String
    Default: 192.168.192.0/14
    Description: CidrBlock for subnet 04 within the VPC

Resources:
  Subnet01:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 01
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '0'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: Subnet01Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Services-Subnet01"

  Subnet02:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 02
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '1'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: Subnet02Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Services-Subnet02"

  Subnet03:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 03
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '2'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: Subnet03Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Services-Subnet03"

  Subnet04:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Metadata:
      Comment: Subnet 04
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone:
        Fn::Select:
        - '3'
        - Fn::GetAZs:
            Ref: AWS::Region
      CidrBlock:
        Ref: Subnet04Block
      VpcId:
        Ref: VPC
      Tags:
      - Key: Name
        Value: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-Services-Subnet04"
```

I am deploying this template in us-west-2 region.
Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to create 4 subnets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the different Regions in AWS have different numbers of Availability Zones (AZs) ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-regions-availability-zones.html)).

Since you are in the region `us-west-2`, you have only 3 AZs. Other regions, like `us-east-1`, have more. The AZs for your region can be found using:

```
▶ aws ec2 describe-availability-zones --region us-west-2 --query 'AvailabilityZones[].ZoneName' 
[
    "us-west-2a", 
    "us-west-2b", 
    "us-west-2c"
]
```

Meanwhile, the intrinsic function [`Fn::GetAZs`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html) returns the AZs to you as an array. You referred to element 3 of that array (i.e. the 4th) and it doesn't exist, and that's why you see that error message.

You probably need to choose between moving to a different region, having a different number of subnets, or having one AZ with 2 subnets and the rest with 1.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Then can you give me one suggestion? If I want to create 6 subnets in VPC via cloudformation in us-west-2 region. How can I create if there is required no of AZs does not exist?

Comment: So you would just put 2 Subnets in each. Start your subnets at 192.168.0.0/19, 192.168.32.0/19 etc, then Fn::Select 0, Fn::Select 1, Fn::Select 2, and then repeat, Fn::Select 0, Fn::Select 1, Fn::Select 2 again. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. It helped me to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case if anyone of you are wondering, why my stack is still failing after updating the right index for the availability zone, there is a caveat.

As per the documentation for [Fn::GetAZs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones.html#intrinsic-function-reference-getavailabilityzones),

> For the EC2-Classic platform, the Fn::GetAZs function returns all
> Availability Zones for a region. For the EC2-VPC platform, the
> Fn::GetAZs function returns only Availability Zones that have a
> default subnet unless none of the Availability Zones has a default
> subnet; in that case, all Availability Zones are returned.

If you don't have a default subnet in the particular Availablity zone, create one as below.

```
─($:~/anraj)─- aws ec2 create-default-subnet --availability-zone us-west-2c
{
    "Subnet": {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2c",
        "AvailableIpAddressCount": 4091,
        "CidrBlock": "172.31.32.0/20",
        "DefaultForAz": true,
        "MapPublicIpOnLaunch": true,
        "State": "available",
        "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxxxxxxxx",
        "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxxx",
        "OwnerId": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "AssignIpv6AddressOnCreation": false,
        "Ipv6CidrBlockAssociationSet": [],
        "Tags": []
    }
}
```

Cheers!